# Adding columns of a lot of databases

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a large number (500, 1000, 10000?) of databases, each containing a table named `my_table`. Each of the `my_table` tables looks like:

```
my_index | value
1        | x_1
2        | x_2
4        | x_4
...      | ...
```

Sometimes, like in this example, the column `my_index` has a missing value (here, 3). I would like to obtain an SQLite table containing

```
my_index | value
1        | sum of the first value of all tables that contain index 1
2        | sum of the second value of all tables that contain index 2
3        | sum of the third value of all tables that contain index 3
...      | ...
```

The way I handle all the databases is through the Sqlite API for Python `sqlite3`. I can think of a lot of very inefficient ways to do that, the most awful being probably:

1. Create a new table `my_big_table` in a new database;
2. for each `my_table`,

   - load the data in a `pandas` DataFrame;
   - transfer the DataFrame to `my_big_table` by appending the new data under the data that is already present;
3. create a new table using the query

```
CREATE TABLE my_nice_table AS
SELECT
    my_index,
    SUM(value)
FROM my_big_table
GROUP BY my_index
;
```

but I have no idea how to perform the task efficiently. I believe that I have read somewhere that concatenating of DataFrames is a bad idea, so I guess creating a lot of DataFrames is a bad idea too; I have also read that in order to transfer data from some database to another, the `ATTACH` command is useful, but also that there is a limit on the number of databases that can be attached.

My questions are: **can you suggest an efficient/elegant way of solving my problem? Are there general principles that one should follow in the situation where there are a lot of databases, each containing tables with similar structure, and one wishes to do some sort of comparison between all these tables?**

Comment: You probably can't attach all databases at once but you can attach up to the limit, update a table by adding the values from all attached dbs, then detach them and attach the next bunch.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know one could detach databases!